# Double ampersand selector in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to port a component from less to sass.
I have this configuration in less:

```
.datepicker {

    &&-rtl {
             ...

    }
}
```

which of course is giving me an error in compiling with SASS.

What I would like to have is this css:

```
.datepicker {

}
.datepicker.datepicker-rtl {

}
```

I have 3.3.3 version of SASS.

Is there any good alternative to this syntax? I've looked ad the documentation but couldn't find a solution.

Thank you so much.

Comment: For the sake of argument, would there be any other class that would have `.datepicker-rtl` other than `.datepicker`? If not, then you don't need the extra specificity, and you can safely just use `&-rtl`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A simple solution is just repeating the `datepicker` class

```
.datepicker {
    /* your properties here, e.g. */
    width: 100%;

    &.datepicker-rtl {
        /* your properties here, e.g. */
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

otherwise you may assign a variable with the class name, like so

```
$dp : datepicker;

.#{$dp} {
    /* your properties here, e.g. */
    width: 100%;

    &.#{$dp}-rtl {
        /* your properties here, e.g. */
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

You can test this syntax here: http://sassmeister.com/

Comment: Works for my project and it's a very smart solution. Anyway, I think double ampersand selector is very useful. Thank you so much.

Comment: WIth today versions of sass you can also use `&.&-rtl` selector.

Answer (score 38):

I know this question is a bit old, but i just want to show another working solution for this.

This example:

```
.datepicker {
    /* your properties here, e.g. */
    width: 100%;

    &#{&}-rtl {
        /* your properties here, e.g. */
        width: 200%;
    }
}
```

will result in:

```
.datepicker {
    /* your properties here, e.g. */
    width: 100%;
}    
.datepicker.datepicker-rtl {
    /* your properties here, e.g. */
    width: 200%;
}
```

Comment: best solution no doubts!